# Is it possible to upgrade Windows 8 Basic to Windows 8 Pro using Windows Upgrade Offer without Windows 7 Key

Tags: windows-8

I have recently purchased a DELL Laptop which comes with Windows 8 Basic. Is it possible to upgrade that to PRO version with the offer.

Comment: Your question and Title ask 2 different questions.

Comment: The answer to this question is `No` the offer only applies to previous versions of Windows and the certain preview versions of Windows 8.  In the case of the preview versions it would require you reinstall the operating system.  The only supported method is to use the built in tool within Windows 8 to do so.  You don't get to upgrade to a more expensive operating system for less money then its being sold for.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

**What is the Windows Upgrade Offer?**
If you buy a qualified Windows 7 PC between June 2, 2012 and January 31, 2013, you can purchase a download of Windows 8 Pro at a special promotional price that varies by region.

**Already purchased a Windows 7 PC?**
Great, we’ve still got you covered. If you bought a PC preinstalled with Windows 7 Home Basic, Home Premium, Professional, or Ultimate on or after June 2, 2012, just go to windowsupgradeoffer.com and register.

[More information](http://www.windowsupgradeoffer.com)